# c# name or type not found

Tags: c#, compilation

```
    private void changeFont()
    {
        Control.ControlCollection controls = tabControl1.Controls;
        foreach (Control control in controls)
        {
            TabPage t = (TabPage)control;
            Control c = t.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(250, 250));
            System.Type type = typeof(c);  //-->1st error
            ((type)c).changeFont(fontModifier); //-->2nd error
        }
    }
```

Error 1 The type or namespace name 'c' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
Error 2 The type or namespace name 'type' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What's wrong with it? Just for the context, i'm trying to go through the tabcontrol and in each tabpage we have a user control, so that's why the getChildAtPoint is that particular position. In all the usercontrols, we have a changefont function that'll change the size of the font of specific controls....

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

To get the actual type of an object, instead of [typeof](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs%28VS.71%29.aspx), which gets the type for a type name (as in `typeof(string)`), you need to use [c.GetType()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.gettype.aspx), which gets the actual type of the object pointed by `c`.

As for `(type)c`, you can't do that: type casting works only by using a specific type name. If you need to invoke the `changeFont` method only in controls that are of, or derive from your custom control type, you should do:

```
if(typeof(MyControlType).IsAssignableFrom(c.GetType()) {
    ((MyControlType)c).changeFont(fontModifier);
}
```

Or, even easier:

```
var myControl = c as MyControlType;
if(myControl != null) {
    myControl.changeFont(fontModifier);
}
```

Comment: the first one works, thanks :)
the second one however...
i have:
                System.Type Type = c.GetType();
                ((Type)c).changeFont(fontModifier);
was that what you meant? because visual studio thinks that Type (2nd line) is refering to System.Type rather than the variable.

Comment: By the way where is the `changeFont` method defined?

Comment: On your last line you have to cast it to a specified type to be able to call methods for that type.

Comment: that's why i was trying to do the (type)c.changeFont(.....) thing... but i guess i did it wrong?

Comment: so i have to make them all part of the same interface or something? Thanks

Comment: yes ladidadida, and all of those controls should implement changeFont

Answer (score 0):

if all the usercontrols have a changeFont function, I presume implementation of a class/interface.

```
private void changeFont()
{
    Control.ControlCollection controls = tabControl1.Controls;
    foreach (Control control in controls)
    {
        TabPage t = (TabPage)control;
        Control c = t.GetChildAtPoint(new Point(250, 250));
        if (c is <your class>)
        {
            (<yourclass>)c.changeFont(fontModifier);
        }
    }
}
```